# How to convert Buffered Image to Image while using URLImage in [CodenameOne]

Tags: image, bufferedimage, codenameone

with the below code am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be cast to com.codename1.ui.Image` error. how can i solve this ?

```
EncodedImage encImage = (EncodedImage) fetchResourceFile().getImage("user2.png");
Image profileImage= URLImage.createToStorage(encImage, "Medium_me.jpg", profile.getProfileImageURL(),URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);         
System.out.println("Imaged:" + profileImage.getImage());

findPlayerImageGs(f).setIcon((Image) profileImage.getImage()); //Error Line
findPlayerImageGs(f).repaint();
```

findPlayerImageGs is Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following modified code and it should work

```
EncodedImage encImage = (EncodedImage)      
fetchResourceFile().getImage("user2.png");
Image profileImage= URLImage.createToStorage(encImage, "Medium_me.jpg",      profile.getProfileImageURL(),URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);         
System.out.println("Imaged:" + profileImage.getImage());
**findPlayerImageGs(f).setIcon(profileImage); //it should work**
findPlayerImageGs(f).repaint();
```

Notice that you shouldn't manipulate `URLImage` and always add it "as is" otherwise it might fail as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html#_urlimage).

The `getImage()` method of image returns a platform native version of the image. This is mostly useless to you as a developer as the platform native image differs in each platform, in JavaSE or the simulator image is implemented via AWT's `BufferedImage`. On iOS you would get a `long[]` pointing at the memory area where the native Objective-C image is held.

This method exists so native code can get access to a platform dependent handle.

Comment: I tried using this only at first, there is no any error and no any output also. see the 4th line if you remove `.getImage()` you will get null.

Comment: are you sure there is image in the following url 
url = profile.getProfileImageURL()

and it takes certain time to load image from url
and make sure there is internet available

Comment: Added some clarifications to the original answer